# Limit of positive infinity plus negative infinity

Tags: limits

When trying to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to {\pi \over 2}}\left({1\over x-{\pi \over 2}}+\tan(x)\right)$$

it becomes $\infty^-+\infty^+$. What techniques can be used for solving this?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form you can try to transform your limit to the '0/0' form.

Comment: The notation $\infty^{\pm}$ doesn't make much sense. It's $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\dfrac\pi2-x=y,y\to0$

$$\tan x+\dfrac1{x-\dfrac\pi2}=\dfrac1{\tan y}-\dfrac1y=\dfrac{y-\tan y}{y^3}\cdot\dfrac{y^3}{y\tan y}$$

Use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)